# Creating my first soap request

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I'm fairly new to web services/api calls

I've been given a wsdl for development.

http://bogus.com/SM/7/ServiceCatalogAPI.wsdl

I've added a service reference to the wsdl using Visual Studio 2010 c# .net 4.0

I've been given a username/password (basic authentication)

I'm looking for guidance on how to do the request. Am I on the right path?

I have the following, but I'm receiving 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'SM9.ServiceReference1.StringType'

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ServiceReference1.CreateCartRequest createCart = new ServiceReference1.CreateCartRequest();

        string result = createCart.model.instance.BriefDescription = "Testing SM9";

        Label1.Text = result.ToString();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

**SOAP Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7" xmlns:cmn="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7/Common">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns:CreateCartRequest>
      <ns:model>
        <ns:keys/>
        <ns:instance>
          <ns:BriefDescription type="">Brief Description</ns:BriefDescription>
          <ns:Description type="">
            <ns:Description type="">description 1</ns:Description>
            <ns:Description type="">description 2</ns:Description>
          </ns:Description>
        </ns:instance>
      </ns:model>
    </ns:CreateCartRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**SOAP Response**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <CreateCartResponse message="Success" returnCode="0" schemaRevisionDate="2012-09-12" schemaRevisionLevel="0" status="SUCCESS" xmlns="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7" xmlns:cmn="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7/Common" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7 http://SE104636.devfg.RBC.com:12700/SM/7/Cart.xsd">
      <model>
        <keys>
          <CartID type="Decimal">11</CartID>
        </keys>
        <instance recordid="11" uniquequery="cartId=11">
          <CartID type="Decimal">11</CartID>
          <Completed type="Boolean">false</Completed>
          <BriefDescription type="String">Brief Description</BriefDescription>
          <Owner type="String">SOAP USER</Owner>
          <Description type="Array">
            <Description type="String">description 1</Description>
            <Description type="String">description 2</Description>
          </Description>
          <Cost type="Decimal">0</Cost>
        </instance>
      </model>
      <messages>
        <cmn:message>svcCart record added.</cmn:message>
      </messages>
    </CreateCartResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Comment: I don't see any actual calls to the webservice, where did you get your response from?

Comment: Hi Hanno, the request and response were included in documentation. I'm trying to figure out how to make my first call.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `BriefDescription` is not of type string.  Try something like this:

```
string result = createCart.model.instance.BriefDescription = new StringType("Testing SM9");
```

or

```
 string result = createCart.model.instance.BriefDescription = new StringType() { Value = "Testing SM9" };
```

(Sorry I don't know what properties "StringType" actually has).

Comment: Hi Appclay, thank you for your response. I tried both examples you provided.Error 1 'SM9.ServiceReference1.StringType' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments 
 Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'SM9.ServiceReference1.StringType' to 'string'

Comment: The error is telling you that you are trying to set something that is of type "SM9.ServiceReference1.StringType" to something that is of type "string".  I'm only guessing with my answer, as I don't have your code to test it with.